# What’s the right ordering for the pronouns "he, you and I"?

Tags: word-order, pronouns

> He, you and I will go for a movie tomorrow.

How to rearrange the pronouns in the best possible manner?

Answer (score 4):

Normally, *you* comes first, hence

> You, he, and I will go for a movie tomorrow.

https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/personal-pronouns

> When more than one personal pronoun is used with a verb, the order is normally: 3rd or 2nd person before 1st person; 2nd person before 3rd person.

> She and I do not get on very well.

> You and he should buy the boat between you.

Comment: I could not get the last sentence. What does it mean?

Comment: That is quoted from the guide you can retrieve from the link and is an illustration that 2nd person comes before 3rd person.

Comment: Buying something "between" two or more people means that each person pays part of the cost, and usually becomes part-owner (unless they're buying a gift etc).